# WP7 how to make menu with tiles?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am new to Silverlight and I believe my question is very simple, but haven't found an answer anywhere. So, I have an application and I want to make my menu to look like the tiles in WP7. I have decided to use a button control for every tile, but I have the feeling, that this isn't the best decision. When user clicks on a button, the button changes its design(background color, forecolor, etc.) to indicate, that it has been clicked. On my WP7 the tiles are designed differently. When user clicks on it, it kind of go downs(sinks) to indicate, that it has been clicked. So, my question is: **Is there an easy way to simulate the natural Tiles behaviour, when they are clicked or I have to build my own behaviours on the button control?**

Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This effect is called the "Tilt effect":

> The tilt effect for Windows Phone
>   controls provides you with the ability
>   to add additional visual feedback for
>   control interaction. Instead of having
>   standard pressed or un-pressed states,
>   controls with the tilt effect provide
>   motion during manipulation. The result
>   is a “tilt” like response when the
>   control is touched.

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941094(v=vs.92).aspx) for an overview of the effect and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx) some sample code.

If you don't want your buttons to change colors when clicked, you can create a copy of the `Button` default template and edit it.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [**TileSlider**](http://tileslider.codeplex.com/).

TileSlider is a control for Windows Phone 7 that lets the developer present a tile in their app that behaves like the tiles when you pin a contact to the start menu.